# Dictionary returns only last key value pairs inside for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a list of strings as:

```
A = [
    'philadelphia court excessive disappointed court hope hope',
    'hope hope jurisdiction obscures acquittal court',
    'mention hope maryland signal held mention problem internal reform life bolster level grievance'
    ]
```

and another list as:

```
B = ['court', 'hope', 'mention', 'life', 'bolster', 'internal', 'level']
```

I want to create dictionary based on occurrence counts of list words `B` in list of strings `A`. Something like,

```
C = [
        {'count':2,'hope':2,'mention':0,'life':0,'bolster':0,'internal':0,'level':0},
        {'count':1,'hope':2,'mention':0,'life':0,'bolster':0,'internal':0,'level':0},
        {'count':0,'hope':1,'mention':2,'life':1,'bolster':1,'internal':1,'level':1}
    ]
```

What I did like,

```
dic={}
for i in A:
    t=i.split()
    for j in B:
        dic[j]=t.count(j)
```

But,it returns only last pair of dictionary,

`print (dic)`

```
{'court': 0,
 'hope': 1,
 'mention': 2,
 'life': 1,
 'bolster': 1,
 'internal': 1,
 'level': 1}
```

Comment: "I want to create dictionary" is actually not true, you are trying to create a list of dictionaries. Hence need to append dictionaries to a list. Also pay attention to where you are initializing the `dic`. Please check my answer.

Comment: You might improve your code a little using `collections.Counter` rather than explicitly counting things yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```py
from collections import Counter

A = ['philadelphia court excessive disappointed court hope hope',
     'hope hope jurisdiction obscures acquittal court',
     'mention hope maryland signal held mention problem internal reform life bolster level grievance']

B = ['court', 'hope', 'mention', 'life', 'bolster', 'internal', 'level']

result = [{b: dict(Counter(i.split())).get(b, 0) for b in B} for i in A]
print(result)
```

**output:**

```sh
[{'court': 2, 'hope': 2, 'mention': 0, 'life': 0, 'bolster': 0, 'internal': 0, 'level': 0}, {'court': 1, 'hope': 2, 'mention': 0, 'life': 0, 'bolster': 0, 'internal': 0, 'level': 0}, {'court': 0, 'hope': 1, 'mention': 2, 'life': 1, 'bolster': 1, 'internal': 1, 'level': 1}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating a list of dicts as in your example output, you are only creating a single dict (and overwriting the word counts each time you check a phrase). You could use `re.findall` to count the word occurrences in each phrase (which has the benefit of not failing if any of your phrases contain words followed by punctuation such as "hope?").

```
import re

words = ['court', 'hope', 'mention', 'life', 'bolster', 'internal', 'level']
phrases = ['philadelphia court excessive disappointed court hope hope','hope hope jurisdiction obscures acquittal court','mention hope maryland signal held mention problem internal reform life bolster level grievance']

counts = [{w: len(re.findall(r'\b{}\b'.format(w), p)) for w in words} for p in phrases]

print(counts)
# [{'court': 2, 'hope': 2, 'mention': 0, 'life': 0, 'bolster': 0, 'internal': 0, 'level': 0}, {'court': 1, 'hope': 2, 'mention': 0, 'life': 0, 'bolster': 0, 'internal': 0, 'level': 0}, {'court': 0, 'hope': 1, 'mention': 2, 'life': 1, 'bolster': 1, 'internal': 1, 'level': 1}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Two issues: You are initializing the `dic` at the wrong place and not collecting those `dic`s in a list. Here is the fix:

```
C = []    
for i in A:
    dic = {}
    t=i.split()
    for j in B:
        dic[j]=t.count(j)
    C.append(dic)
# Result:
[{'court': 2, 'hope': 2, 'mention': 0, 'life': 0, 'bolster': 0, 'internal': 0, 'level': 0},
{'court': 1, 'hope': 2, 'mention': 0, 'life': 0, 'bolster': 0, 'internal': 0, 'level': 0},
{'court': 0, 'hope': 1, 'mention': 2, 'life': 1, 'bolster': 1, 'internal': 1, 'level': 1}]
```

Comment: @Learner of course! Please don't forget to accept the most helpful answer. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I will do it for sure. Just want to ask that I have quiet big list of strings of length around 100,000. Does for loop would increase computation time here?

Comment: @Learner Since you have to iterate on both lists, on each element without exception, I think the double loops are unavoidable.

Comment: Yeah, I have used your code for same. It took a long to compute the results. Do you have any better approach for same? It will be so helpful

Comment: @Learner Please check out parallel processing - multithreading in Python. That way you can break the job into a number of pieces which run in parallel and reduce the time significantly.

Answer (score 0):

You always overwrite the existing values in dict `dic` with `dict[j]=t.count(j)`. You could create a new dict for every i and append it to a list like:

```
dic=[]
for i in A:
    i_dict = {}
    t=i.split()
    for j in B:
        i_dict[j]=t.count(j)
    dic.append(i_dict)
print(dic)
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid overwriting existing values, check if the entry is already in the dictionary. Try adding:

```
if j in b:
    dic[j] += t.count(j)
else:
    dic[j] = t.count(j)
```

Comment: I did something, `dic=[]
for i in A:
    i_dict = {}
    t=i.split()
    for j in B:
        if j in t:
            i_dict[j] += t.count(j)
        else:
            i_dict[j] = t.count(j)
    dic.append(i_dict)` gives error `KeyError: 'court'`